Recursive function to transform JSON to "dot notation"
I'm trying to get something working in Powershell where I can take a typical JSON file and restructure it so that it's represented in a sort of dot notation form.
As an input I'm reading in a JSON file. If, for example, the file looked something like:
{
    "Logging": {
        "MinLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Override": {
                "Host": "Warning"
            }
        },

        "Properties": {
            "ApplicationName": "My App"
        }
    },
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "string"
    }
}



... and from that, I'd like to end up with something flattened out but retaining the paths to the elements:
"Logging.MinLevel.Default" : "Information"
"Logging.MinLevel.Override.Host" : "Warning"
"Properties.ApplicationName" : "My App"

...

This is what I've been working towards and I think I'm sort of heading in the right direction but I've got pretty lost now. Here's my code:
function ConvertTo-DotNotation {
  param(
    [pscustomobject] $jsonObject,
    [string] $splitWith = ":",
    [string] $currentKey = ""
  )

  # Get all object members that we're interested in
  $jsonObjectProperties = $jsonObject | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty

  # Loop through each property and get the key and the corresponding value
  foreach ($property in $jsonObjectProperties) {
    $key = $property.Name
    $value = $jsonObject.$key
    $keyToPrepend = $key
    

    # Check if the value is an object itself
    if ($value -is [pscustomobject]) {
      Write-Host "val is an object, need to recurse"
      $nestedResult = ConvertTo-DotNotation -jsonObject $value -currentKey $keyToPrepend 
      # unsure what to set as result????

    } else {
      #unsure what to set as result ????
    }

    return $result
  }
}

$appsettingsjson = Get-Content -Path ./AppSettingsJSON/regular_json_file.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$flattenedAppsettings = ConvertTo-DotNotation -jsonObject $appsettingsjson

Any pointers on this? Alternative approaches also welcome if I'm making a meal of this...
Thanks

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish here. Can you provide some sample input and output pairs?

Apologies for the lack of examples, had an awful day, wasn't thinking clearly... I added some desired input/output. Hopefully it helps.

The linked duplicate isn't a precise duplicate in terms of the question, but this answer there implements what you're looking for.

FYI: I have added an additional answer to the duplicate.
